# Issues with FindResource()

Tags: c++, resources

I'm working on a piece of code that interacts with Resources (Executables) however i'm currently having a few issues.

**Issue 1**
In the Resource Header File (resource1.h), ID_EXEC is defined to a number however when I use the function "MAKEINTRESOURCE()" and use ID_EXEC as the parameter, ID_EXEC is apparently an undeclared identifier, How can I fix this?

**Issue 2**
The first parameter in FindResource() requires a HMODULE, however I don't know how to get the HMODULE of the executable (Stored within the EXE), How can I get the HMODULE?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Surely your forgot `#include "resource1.h"`

2) It is the value of the first argument that got passed to WinMain(), cast to HMODULE.  If you only have a main() or don't have ready access to the variable then you can use GetModuleHandle(NULL).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Issue 1 is fixed now. However, if the executable is called "source.exe" for example, how can I specify to find that resource?